# Couchbase MuteteInResult always returns Index 0 is invalid error

Tags: java, couchbase

In couchbase java sdk I am trying to change a Boolean field in database.

I am trying to do as following:

```
public boolean changeDataFetchOrder(String caseId, String taskId, boolean isRandom) {
    var searchId = "case" + ":" + caseId + ":" + taskId;
    Collection collection = bucket.defaultCollection();
    
    var result = collection.mutateIn(searchId, Collections.singletonList(
            upsert("isDataFetchOrderRandom", isRandom)
    ));
    
    return result.contentAs(0, Boolean.class);
}
```

This operation changes the field in database but it does not returns result of operation.
Should I do an extra configuration?

```
com.couchbase.client.core.error.InvalidArgumentException: Index 0 is invalid
    at com.couchbase.client.core.error.InvalidArgumentException.fromMessage(InvalidArgumentException.java:28) ~[core-io-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.java.kv.MutateInResult.getFieldAtIndex(MutateInResult.java:118) ~[java-client-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.java.kv.MutateInResult.contentAs(MutateInResult.java:91) ~[java-client-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.java.kv.MutateInResult.contentAs(MutateInResult.java:68) ~[java-client-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.company.caseuploadapi.service.couchbase.CaseRepositoryImpl.changeDataFetchOrder(CaseRepositoryImpl.java:179) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.company.caseuploadapi.service.cases.defaults.CaseService.setDataFetchOrder(CaseService.java:371) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.company.caseuploadapi.controller.CaseController.setDataFetchOrder(CaseController.java:79) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
"}
```

Comment: This was also posted on the Couchbase forums here: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-muteteinresult-always-returns-index-0-is-invalid-error/33746.  Please see there for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thansk to @Graham Pole, it was answered in Couchbase forum. I am quoting:

> Yes, most mutateIn operations don’t return what they’ve written. This
> is because generally you know what that is - e.g. you have isRandom
> here - and it saves bytes on the wire.
>
> The exception are counters: if you increment or decrement a counter,
> it does return what was written, since you otherwise wouldn’t that
> information.

See the discussion [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-muteteinresult-always-returns-index-0-is-invalid-error/33746)